# FFMPEG & OPENGL - RAW Frames

Tags: c++, opengl, ffmpeg, recording, video-recording

I'm building a recorder using a BlackMagic DeckLink Card.
The program is using OpenGL to display the Frames and FFMPEG (with the glReadPixels() method) to record them.
I'm setting the viewport in my program to apply a automatic letter-/pillarbox whether the Image/Monitor is 16:9/4:3.
The problem with that ist that when i capture these frames of this viewport they get of course recorded in the resolution my viewport is (i.e. Full Hd source -> viewport due to monitor with 1600x1200 resolution -> letterbox down to 1600x900) and so FFMPEG records those 1600x1200 with  black bars at the top/bottom.

Is there any possibility to grab the RAW Frame before it gets passed trough the setViewport function and all the rescaling stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at some point the image is passed to OpenGL. Why don't you just take that data and pass it to FFMPEG directly instead of doing the lengthy, inefficient and expensive round trip through OpenGL.

If OpenGL is used for realtime colorspace conversion, that I suggest you do that rendering to a FBO with a texture attached with the size of the video resolution, use a glReadPixels on that FBO (preferrably into a PBO); and finally draw that rendered to texture onto the main screen in that window resolution.

However if you can simply feed the raw frames directly to FFMPEG (which can do colorspace conversions as well) I strongly suggest you do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I think method one would be rather difficult as I think the Image gets passed in some propretairy Format (I think).   
[HERE](http://pastebin.com/9hQQ1sAB) is a link to my code that handles the whole OpenGL stuff. Note the method "DrawFrame", it gets some weird "IDeckLinkVideoFrame" Format. It would be great if you could look into the code, I'm very new to OpenGL and C++

Comment: Typing "IDeckLinkVideoFrame" into Google gives me a DeckLinkAPI.h file. IDeckLinkVideoFrame is a so called "abstract" interface class. There's some subclass of it, implementing the so called "purely virtual functions" of that class. The relevant functions are all there https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxBlackmagic/blob/master/libs/DeckLink/include/DeckLinkAPI.h#L567

Comment: @MarcoReisacher: The functions of the IDeckLinkVideoFrame give you information about the frame format and the raw pixel bytes. That's everything you require. It's what gets passed to OpenGL and it's also what you can pass to FFmpeg.

Comment: Sounds like some good news. How do I pass this then? Using the glReadPixels will not work I think. Sorry for the noob questions, but I'm still learning all that stuff

Comment: I think I got in now. I have to use the GetBytes function on the frame by calling `theFrame->GetBytes(buffer)`. Then process that buffer with FFMPEG. But when I pass my buffer using that function I get an access violation error, although in the source code the buffer that gets passed to the "GetBytes" function is marked as "/out/". See the error [here](http://i.imgur.com/HQJ5fyt.png)

Comment: @MarcoReisacher: What type is buffer? I don't see how you declared it, but judging from the method signature you should probably use something like `void *buffer; theFrame->GetBytes(&buffer);` then `buffer` holds a void pointer to the actual data. You can then cast that appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! That took me a step further. Now I record the Video raw and it is not anymore dependent of the preview Size. But I get wrong Colors and the Image multiple times within my Videos. Also the bottom line it twitching. See [here](http://imgur.com/a/70dz2). Code [here](http://pastebin.com/tUeMvhBk). I think the Color are because I'm feeding YpbPr and FFMPEG expects something else (Though it worked before using raw Video). It would be great to get that automated, because the Input signals will vary (FBAS, Composite, YpbPr). But I cant seem to find a function of the SDK to get the source type.

Comment: @MarcoReisacher: The source type would be the pixelformat and you can query that using the `GetPixelFormat` function. Regarding the way your image looks this is some kind of planar format, for which the rows seem to require some alignment. Anyway BDMPixelFormat is an enum and you can use it to find out, what beast you're dealing with. BTW: FFmpeg can talk to BlackMagic devices. Everytime I Google something from the DeckLink API some link into FFmpeg code repositories comes up first.

Comment: Wow, I've searched so Long for OpenGL and ffmpeg but never considered this :). I Looks good when I start it on the commandline with `"ffmpeg -f decklink -i "DeckLink Studio 4K@11" -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.avi"`. But when i start it in my program using `const char* cmd = "ffmpeg -f decklink -i ""DeckLink Studio 4K@11"" -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.avi";` , followed by `ffmpeg = _popen (cmd, "wb");` .It flashes at me quickly and Closes again. Am I missing something? I think that should be the same

Comment: @MarcoReisacher: Look at this: `…-i ""DeckLink Studio 4K@11""` you're not properly escaping the quotes here, so ffmpeg just gets `DeckLink` passed for the `-i` parameter and the `Studio 4K@11` part get interpreted as non-options. You have to quote the string differently, namely `"… -i \"DeckLink Studio 4K@11\"… "`. Of course you also may run into some popen semantics. In case of doubt, fork+dup2+execv it, passing the parameters as an array of strings. But I can see that the fork+dup2+execv dance could be a bit tricky for a newbie.

Comment: BTW: OpenGL cares about only one thing: Drawing points lines and triangles to the screen using texture data and shader programs to control the drawing operations. Reading back pixels using OpenGL is required mostly for implementing multiple render passes and for retrieving the results of off-screen rendering. But OpenGL is not meant to be used for general purpose image manipulation. If you want to do GPU accelerated image operations often a true compute system like OpenCL or CUDA is much more straightforward to use.

Comment: Good 2 know. It is still flashing up and closing. Is there a quick&easy way to force the cmd to stay open, so I can see what is wrong

Comment: Damn, that could be a Show stopper. The Problem is (quite sure) is that the DeckLink device is blocked by OpenGL thus ffmpeg can't hook to it and recieve data. When I open my program and open a cmd side by side and type in the ffmpeg command I get "Cannot enable video Input".
Is there any way around it. I don't get that error when my proram is closed and I run the command

Comment: @MarcoReisacher: You could start your program from a command line window, then all the output will end up there and after terminating the command line window stays with a prompt. Also OpenGL should not block anything. There are no truly blocking calls in OpenGL. The worst that can happen is a command triggering a synchronization point, making the program wait for a couple of µs to ms until operations have finished.

Comment: Opening in command didn't work unfortunately, ffmpeg Pops open in a new window. I tested around a bit, it seems some part of the sdk is blockin the Card (presumably the one that is grabbing the Frames). I can not open ffmpeg with my program running, nor with the Blackmagic Media Express. I read something about piping would be helpful or running ffmpeg as c-code directly on the program (not opening the .exe like I do), but honestly that is just way to hard for me as a total newbie

Comment: @MarcoReisacher: I'd not try to focus too hard on the ffmpeg part. That one is easy once you've got the frame data. Instead I'd focus on getting the frame data properly read out. You'll have to bite the bullet familiarizing yourself with the various pixelformats there are (chroma subsampling, planar vs. interleaved formats and so on). There's already that OpenGL display, which means at some point the data is fed from the IDeckLink… to GL. OpenGL is dumb, it doesn't know how to decode images; so in proximity to the OpenGL code the format conversion should be found (or in some OpengL shaders).

Comment: @MarcoReisacher: So I'd start looking for functions that transfer image data into OpenGL. Something like `glTexImage2D` `glTexSubImage2D`; maybe this is happening through PBOs, so look also for `glBufferData` `glBufferSubData` `glMapBuffer` and `glUnmapBuffer`.

Comment: I looked trough the code but wasn't able to find one of those functions. However I found them in some other examples of the DeckLink SDK (one Mac, one Windows) -> see [here](https://github.com/HalfdanJ/VideoSuiteUtilities/blob/master/libs/Blackmagic%20DeckLink%20SDK%209.6.4/Mac/Samples/Streaming/StreamingPreview/OpenGLPreview.mm#L204) and [here](https://github.com/HalfdanJ/ViljensTriumf2/blob/master/libs/Blackmagic%20DeckLink%20SDK%209.6.4/Linux/Samples/LoopThroughWithOpenGLCompositing/OpenGLComposite.cpp#L311).

Comment: I also looked at the code when the OpenGL Rendering first gets initialized in my main class that also handles the different mode selections. When the capture gets initialized, this method gets called `StartCapture(unsigned int videoModeIndex, IDeckLinkScreenPreviewCallback* screenPreviewCallback, bool applyDetectedInputMode)`. [Here](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxBlackmagic/blob/master/libs/DeckLink/include/DeckLinkAPI.h#L658) is this "IDeckLinkScreenPreviewCallback" that already passes over "theFrame". I don't get it, is the whole OpenGL transfer stuff being initialized internally?

Comment: Just stumbled upon a forum post which confirms my guess "Hello. The way the Blackmagic sdk is designed is that if one program has access to the device, no other programs will have access. It is like this with all applications that utilize Blackmagic devices.". So I guess that's why ffmpeg can't bind to the input device as it is already in use by my program.
I honestly don't know whether i can bypass this by using ffmpeg source code in my program rather than calling the .exe externally with some options

Comment: @MarcoReisacher: Well, that's not too much of a surprise. Suggestion. Push the source code you have so far somewhere and I'll add comments what to do where.

Comment: Ok, you got a dropbox account? I got now two Version. One with non working ffmpeg which is hooking directly to the decklink and one now working with the `glReadPixels`. The working one runs smoothly, but I'd rather use the native one, just for good measure, cause you said OpenGL is not really meant for extensive reading back Pixels. Also the native way allows me to record Audio, which might come in handy

Comment: @MarcoReisacher: I normally don't Dropbox as I normally keep things away from "Cloud" providers; I just set up a account for the occasion by the name of "Franz Nord" (= fnord, on the meaning of it see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fnord)

Comment: Ok, me neither. Here you can get it (but beware it is hosted here on my synology with DSL 16000 :) ) [FTP](ftp://reisacher.org)

Comment: @MarcoReisacher: So I've looked into the code. Oh boy… seems like BlackMagic does all the OpenGL drawing behind the curtain and then this program is actually taking screenshots of the window to feed to FFmpeg. If you move a window in front of the program with desktop compositing disabled (WinXP, Aero turned of in Visa and 7) you'd actually encode the contents of windows overlaying the preview. The good news is, that there's only a handful of pixelformats the deck link gives you and except two all of them are supported by ffmpeg as a pipe input. Decoding it to OpenGL is going to be trickier.

Comment: Damn, thats what I was afraid of. Screenhots? Never heard of passing data this way to FFmpeg. So how do i need to configure FFmpeg with the pipe input. I was so hoping that the native way would work as this would give me easy access to audio as well

Comment: Thanks so much for all the nice help, I think i'll go with the `glReadPixels` method. One last question, is there a way to open the cmd window with ffmpeg minimized. Now it opens right on the previewwindow which is kind of distracting and one has to minimize it

Comment: @MarcoReisacher: Well, the screenshots are done by calling glReadPixels on the preview window. Now depending on your needs you could implement a preview window for FFmpeg  by means of a frei0r filter plugin. Also I thought (but looking at the documentation I can't find it) that there already was a preview display filter available. Regarding the audio, well, it's technically possible to open several pipes and feed multiple streams to ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks again for the effort and answering all my dumb questions. Recording is running